# AFHTTPRequestOperation vs AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm a complete noob to objective c, so please excuse the dumb question.

I've been able to send post and get requests using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager following the guides for AFNetworking 2.0.

I started to look into response caching and from what I could read, AFHTTPRequestOperation has setCachePolicy. I started to switch all my calls to AFHTTPRequestOperation, but I'm finding it difficult to work with.

Am I creating unnecessary work for myself? If the server's cache headers are set correctly, do I need to do anything on the client side with AFNetworking?

With AFHTTPRequestOperationManager:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

With AFHTTPRequestOperation:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

I really hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

**AFHTTPRequestOperation** is a subclass of AFURLConnectionOperation for requests using the HTTP or HTTPS protocols. It encapsulates the concept of acceptable status codes and content types, which determine the success or failure of a request.

**AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** encapsulates the common patterns of communicating with an web application over HTTP, including request creation, response serialization, network reachability monitoring, and security, as well as request operation management.

Comment: so, from what ur saying, they aren't really comparable. AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is the overarching framework for handling web apps over HTTP, and AFHTTPRequestOperation are the individual requests made over HTTP or HTTPS. does that sound right?